# wp_mail strips out the link url from the anchor tag in mail content

Tags: wp-mail, html-email

When the email content contains a link with url like: mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m,
`<a href="mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m">Click</a>` 
wp_mail function removing the url from the anchor tag and the link doesn't work. When the url is appended with/having http://, the link works. Here is the code I am using. Any help or hint will be appriciated !!

Thanks in advance !!

```
$subject = 'Mobile App Activation link';
$activation_url = 'mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m;
$activation_link = '<a href="' . $activation_url . '" title="Verify">' . $activation_url . '</a>';      

$mail_message = '<p>Thank you for signing up with us!</p>';
$mail_message .= '<p>Please click the verification link in order to complete the signup process.</p>';
$mail_message .= '<p>Verification Link: ' . $activation_link . '</p>';

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'mysite_from_name' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'mysite_from_email' );

$res = wp_mail( $user_email, $subject, $mail_message );
```

Email content's source through Firebug looks like this: (href="" is striped out)

```
<a title="Verify" target="_blank">mobileappname://accesstoken#fs2fmhsf4nsv94s</a>
```

Comment: Try using escaping forward slash as following $activation_url = 'mobileappname:\/\/accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m';

Comment: @VinodDalvi No, its not working. Still strips out the href.

This is the html being sent in email content when looked through firebug: 

<a title="Verify" target="_blank">mobileappname:\/\/accesstoken#fs2fmhsf4nsv94s</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a single quote `'`

```
$activation_url = 'mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m;
```

should be...

```
$activation_url = 'mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m';
```

or (using double quotes)...

```
$activation_url = "mobileappname://accesstoken#w34rdgtsrt5v6m";
```

Update:

See this codex entry for more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); // reset content-type to to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578

function set_html_content_type()
{
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Basically you need to remove the plain text filter and replace it with the text/html filter to properly parse the HTML content you are sending via e-mail.

Comment: My bad.. this single quote missed while pasting/editing the question here. This is Ok in my code though. Still this is not working. Any idea how can make this work ?

Comment: Actually yes! I had this problem two weeks ago and it was because I forgot to change the html content type of the `wp_mail_content_type` filter.

Comment: I am already adding the content type filter before calling wp_mail. Now I have added the remove_filter as well. Still issue is there; strips out the herf  :(

Doesn't it support any type of urls in the href ?

Comment: @Subharanjan This is happening because you are using custom protocol mobileappname:// in your url. Refer these links for more information http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/06/Registering-a-custom-protocol-handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome

Comment: @Vinod: Thats correct !! I am using the custom protocol to open the mobile app directly instead of opening the link in the mobile browser. But the mail is stripping out the href url itself. 

When I send a mail from outlook/Thunderbird with the same link, it doesn't strip out the url.